# Adding medium profile in profile section

Tags: pdftex, luatex, cv

I want to add my [medium](https://medium.com) profile in the personal section in my resume. Given that this is my first time using TeX, is there any way to do this. As font awesome is supported, so I added these lines:

```
\newcommand{\mediumsymbol}{\famedium}
\newcommand{\medium}[1]{\printinfo{\mediumsymbol}{#1}}
```

But this is throwing error. Also, the links in personal section are not spaced equally. Is there any way to correct it?

```
\personalinfo{%

  \email{abc@gmail.com}
  \location{XYZ}
  \twitter{@abc}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/abc}
   \github{github.com/abc}
```

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, I am providing a snippet of the file I am using on overleaf:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages.
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=2cm,right=10cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\name{abc}
\tagline{AAAA}
% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
%\photo{3.3cm}{profile.jpg}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{abc@gmail.com}
%   \phone{000-00-0000}
%  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{loc}
  \medium{meidum.com/abc}
%  \twitter{@marissamayer}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/abc}
   \github{github.com/abc} % I'm just making this up though.
%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000} % Obviously making this up too. If you want to use this field (and also other academicons symbols), add "academicons" option to \documentclass{altacv}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question, otherwise it is near-impossible to guess the context of your problem.

Comment: @Mensch thanks for the feedback. I added the snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you did not tell us the error you got. Please always add the complete error message you got to help us to help you ...

Bases on your sadly **not compilable code snippet** (forces us to guess what you are doing, not a good starting point for helping you ...) I can guess that your line

```
\newcommand{\mediumsymbol}{\famedium} % <===============================
```

throws the error that controll sequence `famedium` is undefined. Of course, because the correct command defined in `fontawesome` is `\faMedium` (see big letter M):

```
\newcommand{\mediumsymbol}{\faMedium} % <===============================
```

I added missing code to your code snippet to get it compilable, see the following compilable MWE (without errors):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages.
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=2cm,right=10cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\newcommand{\mediumsymbol}{\faMedium} % <===============================
\newcommand{\medium}[1]{\printinfo{\mediumsymbol}{#1}} 


\begin{document}
\name{abc}
\tagline{AAAA}
% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
%\photo{3.3cm}{profile.jpg}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{abc@gmail.com}
%   \phone{000-00-0000}
%  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{loc}
  \medium{meidum.com/abc}
%  \twitter{@marissamayer}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/abc}
   \github{github.com/abc} % I'm just making this up though.
%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000} % Obviously making this up too. If you want to use this field (and also other academicons symbols), add "academicons" option to \documentclass{altacv}
}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

\cvsection{Experience} % [mmayer-p1sidebar]

\cvevent{President \& CEO}{Yahoo!}{July 2012 -- Ongoing}{Sunnyvale, CA}
\begin{itemize}
\item Led the \$5 billion acquisition of the company with Verizon -- the entity which believed most in the immense value Yahoo!\ has created
\item Acquired Tumblr for \$1.1 billion and moved the company's blog there
\item Built Yahoo's mobile, video and social businesses from nothing in 2011 to \$1.6 billion in GAAP revenue in 2015
\item Tripled the company's mobile base to over 600 million monthly active users and generated over \$1 billion of mobile advertising revenue last year
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Vice President of Location \& Services}{Google}{Oct 2010 -- July 2012}{Palo Alto, CA}
\begin{itemize}
\item Position Google Maps as the world leader in mobile apps and navigation
\item Oversaw 1000+ engineers and product managers working on Google Maps, Google Places and Google Earth
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Vice President of Search Products \& UX}{Google}{2005 --  2010}{Palo Alto, CA}

\divider

\cvevent{Product Manager \& UI Lead}{Google}{Oct 2001 -- July 2005}{Palo Alto, CA}

\begin{itemize}
\item Appointed by the founder Larry Page in 2001 to lead the Product Management and User Interaction teams
\item Optimized Google's homepage and A/B tested every minor detail to increase usability (incl.~spacing between words, color schemes and pixel-by-pixel element alignment)
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{A Day of My Life}

\wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
  10/10em/accent!30/Sleeping \& dreaming about work,
  25/9em/accent!60/Public resolving issues with Yahoo!\ investors,
  5/13em/accent!10/\footnotesize\\[1ex]New York \& San Francisco Ballet Jawbone board member,
  20/15em/accent!40/Spending time with family,
  5/8em/accent!20/\footnotesize Business development for Yahoo!\ after the Verizon acquisition,
  30/9em/accent/Showing Yahoo!\ employees that their work has meaning,
  5/8em/accent!20/Baking cupcakes
}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result]

As you can see with the corrected code the links in personal section are spaced equally. Do not missinterpret the short `loc`, it makes an optical illusion of not spaced equally ...

Comment: Sorry, I will post `error logs` next time for sure